# Removing duplicates by adding them up [SQL]

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a query like this:

```
select employee_id, salary
from salary
left join employee on salary.employee_id=employee.id_employee;
```

It returns me these results

```
EMPLOYEE ID  | SALARY
-------------|-------
1            |     50
2            |     50
3            |     50
1            |     30
```

How do I remove duplicates by adding them up, like this:

```
EMPLOYEE ID |  SALARY
------------|--------
1           |      80
2           |      50
3           |      50
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for a `left join` from `salary` to `employee`.  Presumably, every `employee_id` in `salary` refers to a valid employee.  So, this should do what you want:

```
select s.employee_id, sum(s.salary) as salary
from salary s
group by s.employee_id;
```

If you want *all* employees, even those who are not in the `salary` table, then an outer join is appropriate -- but `employee` should be first:

```
select e.id_employee, sum(s.salary) as salary
from employee e left join
     salary s
     on s.employee_id = e.id_employee
group by e.id_employee;
```

Employees not in `salary` will have a value of `NULL`.

Note that the `group by` condition in this query is on `employee`, the *first* table in the `left join`.

Comment: "If you want all employees, even those who are not in the employee table ..." - shouldn't that be vice  versa? I.e. "those who are not in the salary table"? I'd expect all employees to reside in the EMPLOYEE table, but not all of them should have a record in the SALARY table (for example, because they have just been employed and didn't get their first salary yet).

Answer (score 1):

```
select employee_id, SUM(salary) as salary
from salary
left join employee on salary.employee_id=employee.id_employee
group by emplyee_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what a `group by` clause is for. You'll have to `group by` the `emplopyee_id` and specify how you want to aggregate the salary:

```
SELECT   employee_id, SUM(salary)
FROM     salary
GROUP BY employee_id
```

Comment: `employee_id` not `employee_kd`